# UICollectionView frame update not working

Tags: xcode, ios7, uicollectionview, autolayout

I am using auto layout and I am trying to update the frame of my UICollectionView (which was created in storyboard) in viewDidLoad method of my class by using:

```
myCollectionView.frame = someFrame;
```

However, I have not applied any constraint to the collection view. There is also not any conflicting constraint in my VC.
If I check on log, the frame is updated, but on device, it isn't and old frame is being shown. Kindly guide me.

Comment: Try to call `[myCollectionView setNeedsDisplay];`. But if the `collectionView` is the view of a view controller (and not added with `addSubview` you won't be able to change the frame. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: myCollectionView is inside a View which is the subview of view of VC

Comment: Log the constraints using the [constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/constraints) method of `UIView`. I assume there are constraints on the `myCollectionView`.

Comment: I have removed all auto layout constraints in current VC. It still isn't working.